# Is it possible to achieve the "Aero Glass" look on XP?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-xp, aero

Does anyone know any kind of framework that enables (not exactly the same, but) Vista's Aero Glass on XP?

I need to develop a little desktop application with WPF, which has a Vista-like UI on XP. I don't need exactly the Aero Glass, some UI like "Windows Live Messenger" will do the thing.
Is there any way to make it a reality?

Answer (score 4):

If you really mean Aero **Glass** then I think you're out of luck. The hardware acceleration required to create this effect is only supported via Vista's new DWM (Desktop Window Manager), which works by compositing multiple windows together into one rendered layer.

If you just want transparency and non-rectangular windows then this can definitely be achieved in XP, as evidenced by the fact that Windows Live Messenger can do it. Have a look at [Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: What aspect of Glass requires the Vista DWM?

Comment: Essentially, it requires hardware acceleration for performance, which isn't available under GDI.

Comment: Right. To put it another way. What aspect of Glass requires hardware acceleration considering glass is nothing but ARGB transparency which as you say is available in xp.

Comment: No it's not. Glass is a filtered and blurred transparency effect that is achieved with a csutom PS 2.0 pixel shader. It also relies on DWM composition. If you think Aero Glass is simple alpha-channel transparency then I suggest you look a bit closer.

Comment: Ah right. The blur. I reckon 90% of the glass feel is the transparency and reflections, but indeed it's not quite the same without the blur.

Answer (score 1):

As Stu Mackellar wrote, Windows XP is missing a required piece in order to obtain Aero Glass effect: DWM.
A solution is to create your own "fake" glass effect. Thake a look to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/unnir/archive/2006/03/01/541154.aspx) blog (you can download the code).