# Creating a semi-transparent blurred background WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, blur

I have a border, i want the background of this border to be partially transparent (opacity 0.8) but i do not want the image behind it to be well defined. The effect i am after is similar to the Windows Vista window border effect, where you can see that something is behind it but you cant tell what it is.

A few clarifications:
I am working on Windows XP, so i cant use Vista Glass
I need this solution to be portable across any windows platform

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The apt term would be `translucent border`

Comment: What version of .NET Framework are you using? 3.5? 4.0?

Comment: I recently worked on such a solution.
Here is a way to perform this kind of transparency, based on visualBrush, viewport and blur effect:
http://charly-studio.com/blog/aero-effect-blurry-transparency-in-wpf/

Answer (score 2):

[Extend Glass Frame Into a WPF Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx#Y228)

[WPF Window with aero glass background. (C# .NET)](http://ciantic.blogspot.com/2009/10/wpf-window-with-areo-glass-background-c.html)

[DWM Blur Behind Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969537%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Hope one of those links helps. I used the 1'st link I had to add this class to make it work:

```
#region WINAPI Crap, none should handle this in 21st century
    private class NonClientRegionAPI
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MARGINS
        {
            public int cxLeftWidth;      // width of left border that retains its size
            public int cxRightWidth;     // width of right border that retains its size
            public int cyTopHeight;      // height of top border that retains its size
            public int cyBottomHeight;   // height of bottom border that retains its size
        };


        [DllImport("DwmApi.dll")]
        public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(
            IntPtr hwnd,
            ref MARGINS pMarInset);

    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could find on the net:

http://blogs.msdn.com/unnir/archive/2006/03/01/541154.aspx

Considering the above is by a Microsoft guy, you'd be hard pressed to find a better way to do it.

It does a simple transparency on the window, so not quite like Aero glass. Aero effect is hardware accelerated and most certainly uses Direct3D in some way.

This SO answer talks about it in some detail:

[Is it possible to achieve the "Aero Glass" look on XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484130/is-it-possible-to-achieve-the-aero-glass-look-on-xp/484274#484274)

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. still working on imitating the Aero look, didnt quite get what i was after. Will post here if i do

Comment: I'm currently looking to reproduce the effect as accurately as I can myself as well. Unfortunately the outbound links from this blog post seem completely dead (not in internet archive, googling the filenames produces no effect either). Was this particular circa-2006 implementation any good? Maybe someone out there has buried copies of the files.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight there is a Blur effect (http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/Using-Blur-and-DropShadow-effects-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) should also be available for WPF (http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid8_gci1377157,00.html) you can apply to controls. Maybe combining this with opacity would help you achive the desired goal?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, blur only blurs the visuals within the display area of the control. For instance, if i have a red/whie gradient and i apply a blur, the red/white will blur to a more uniform color in the areas in which the blur is applied (a pinky color) but if it is transparent, the items and text behind the transparect control will still be sharply in focus