# Customize window color for current application

Tags: c#, wpf, transparency

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786336/creating-a-semi-transparent-blurred-background-wpf/6474980#6474980) I managed to get something like:

[image]

The window Files Pro that I created appears with the collor that I select when I go to:

```
Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Window Color and Appearance
```

Is there a way of changing the color so that it will always display the same color regardless of which color is selected for windows?

Comment: No. You can't do that for a single application. DWM dosen't provide this facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to control this.

The best you can hope to do is take over responsibility of drawing the entire frame (icon, caption, minimize, maximize, close buttons, frame, resizing, etc).

Then you can color your window, but the glass effect of Windows will still colorize your window.

---

Since you seem to want to exclude yourself from the look and feel of Windows, your best bet is to give up on glass rendering: [DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969508%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)